# How to assign NSObject to UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios

I have one object - `NSObject`, assigned from NSDictionary have struct as:

```
{
    author = "abc";
    content = "xyz";
    img = "1.gif";
    title = "bla bla"
}
```

So I change to `DetailViewController`, how to assign value -> `UILabel`, I assigned 
Assume

DetailViewController.h,
@property(strong ,nonatomic) UILabel *bookTitle;

how to assign field Title của NSObject - > bookTitle ?

Comment: I don't understand.  Please clarify.

Comment: are you just looking for bookTitle.text = <variable name>.title ?

Comment: sorry my english so bad :( this mean 
i want assign value of NSObject(have struct -json) to UILabel at DetailViewController

Comment: What is the data structure you printed? Is it the contents of the `NSDictionary`?

Comment: Do you want pick the title value inside the `NSDictionary` and put in UILabel?

Comment: @TinCan:i tried ,but don't work,
thanks

Comment: @FabioCardoso;yes that's right

Comment: Can you show your full .h and  .m file, so that we can understand what you want to do.

Comment: Please refer to the documentation for [UILabel](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
controller.bookTitle = data[@"title"];
```

where `controller` is a reference to your `DetailViewController` and `data` is a reference to the `NSDictionary` with the data.